# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'legacy'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm attempting to configure the TensorFlow object detection API [TFOD](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) in a Python virtual environment with python=3.10.9, TensorFlow=2.8.0, CUDA=11.2 and CuDNN=8.1. I've already passed the verification script and everything works fine until I want to train the model and paste the command below into the command prompt:

`python Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet\pipeline.config --num_train_steps=2000`

The error it shows me is:

```
C:\Users\vetran2\pyproj\tfodnew\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\utils\ensure_tf_install.py:53: UserWarning: Tensorflow Addons supports using Python ops for all Tensorflow versions above or equal to 2.9.0 and strictly below 2.12.0 (nightly versions are not supported).
 The versions of TensorFlow you are currently using is 2.8.0 and is not supported.
Some things might work, some things might not.
If you were to encounter a bug, do not file an issue.
If you want to make sure you're using a tested and supported configuration, either change the TensorFlow version or the TensorFlow Addons's version.
You can find the compatibility matrix in TensorFlow Addon's readme:
https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ObjectDetection\TensorFlow Object Detection\TFODCourse\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 31, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
  File "C:\Users\vetran2\pyproj\tfodnew\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.10.egg\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 31, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib
  File "C:\Users\vetran2\pyproj\tfodnew\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.10.egg\object_detection\model_lib.py", line 35, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import optimizer_builder
  File "C:\Users\vetran2\pyproj\tfodnew\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.10.egg\object_detection\builders\optimizer_builder.py", line 25, in <module>
    from official.modeling.optimization import ema_optimizer
  File "C:\Users\vetran2\pyproj\tfodnew\lib\site-packages\tf_models_official-2.11.3-py3.10.egg\official\modeling\optimization\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from official.modeling.optimization.ema_optimizer import ExponentialMovingAverage
  File "C:\Users\vetran2\pyproj\tfodnew\lib\site-packages\tf_models_official-2.11.3-py3.10.egg\official\modeling\optimization\ema_optimizer.py", line 24, in <module>
    class ExponentialMovingAverage(tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Optimizer):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'legacy'
```

Comment: `C:\Users\vetran2\pyproj\tfodnew\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\utils\ensure_tf_install.py:53: UserWarning: Tensorflow Addons supports using Python ops for all Tensorflow versions above or equal to 2.9.0 and strictly below 2.12.0 (nightly versions are not supported).
 The versions of TensorFlow you are currently using is 2.8.0 and is not supported.
Some things might work, some things might not.
If you were to encounter a bug, do not file an issue.`

Comment: You have a version conflict, you should update tensorflow to 2.9.0

Comment: The last line: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'legacy' seems to be a different problem, I try to search and it shows me this:

`Starting from TensorFlow 2.4, the legacy module was removed from tensorflow.keras.optimizers. If you have code that uses the legacy module, you will need to update it to use the new API. For example, if you were using tensorflow.keras.optimizers.sgd from the legacy module, you can replace it with tensorflow.keras.optimizers.SGD.` 

I try to install using pip install tensorflow==2.4.0 but it is not available.

Comment: Hi @Lim Chin Hong, There is a version incompatibility between installed `TensorFlow` and the `tensorflow_addons` version required for this model. Please check the first error line **"Tensorflow Addons supports using Python ops for all Tensorflow versions above or equal to 2.9.0 and strictly below 2.12.0 (nightly versions are not supported)"**. Could you please try again by upgrading the TensorFlow version to 2.9 using `!pip install tensorflow==2.9`. Please check [Python Op Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons#python-op-compatibility-matrix) for the reference.